# How to change the color of the panel(frames) of Chrome in a custom GTK theme?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, themes

so I installed Ubuntu 14.04(with Unity) on Virtual Box and after that I installed Numix theme. After that I tweaked the **gtk.css** file which is in `/usr/share/themes/Numix/gtk-3.0.` I managed to change the colors of selected items and the color of windows panel(frames). But when I open Chrome the color of the its window panel(frame) is the same as the theme came. Other windows panels are the color I wanted, but Chrome is not.

In what file and how I should change the code in order to change the color of Chrome panel(frame)? Thank you.

Comment: Note that I'm very much a newbie in this, but have you looked into editing /usr/share/themes/Numix/gtk-2.0/apps/cromium.rc ... if you have one. Also, I believe the advice is to first copy the Numix theme into a private sub tree at ~/.themes/Numix-meown/ before editing files in there. That theme then automatically comes up as a selectable option, and in that way you can always revert.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This is what I did.

In `/usr/share/themes/<theme name>/gtk-2.0` there is a file called `gtkrc` I opened it using `gksudo gedit <path>`, after I opened the file I found:

```
style "chrome-gtk-frame" {
    ChromeGtkFrame::frame-color = "#444851" #@titlebar_bg_color
    ChromeGtkFrame::inactive-frame-color = "#444851" #@titlebar_bg_color

    ChromeGtkFrame::frame-gradient-size = 0
    ChromeGtkFrame::frame-gradient-color ="#444851" #@titlebar_bg_color

    ChromeGtkFrame::incognito-frame-color ="#444851" #@titlebar_bg_color
    ChromeGtkFrame::incognito-inactive-frame-color ="#444851"#@titlebar_bg_color

    ChromeGtkFrame::incognito-frame-gradient-size = 0
    ChromeGtkFrame::incognito-frame-gradient-color ="#444851" #@titlebar_bg_color

    ChromeGtkFrame::scrollbar-trough-color = @bg_color
    ChromeGtkFrame::scrollbar-slider-normal-color = mix (0.21, @fg_color, @bg_color)
    ChromeGtkFrame::scrollbar-slider-prelight-color = mix (0.31, @fg_color, @bg_color)}
```

The color "#444851" is the color I chose for my chrome.

@tittle_br_color is the default value. I just commented the value.